# Find and replace or add last character to url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to filter URL and see if URL has `/` at the end if not then i have to add `/` to the url

URL could be in either format

```
https://www.example.com/about-us
https://www.example.com/about-us/
```

If URL doent have `/` at the end then i have to add it.

What is the most efficient way of doing it in C#

```
string strURL = 'https://www.example.com/about-us'

if(strURL.EndsWith("/")){
     //Do nothing//
}else{
    strURL = strURL + "/";
}
```

Is above code right approach or it can be improved and maded shorter

Comment: Would prefer checking such: `if(!strURL.EndsWith("/"))`, then append the "/".

Comment: `strURL = strURL.TrimEnd('/') + "/";`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any bad in your approach, but you can make it a bit shorter :

```
string strURL = 'https://www.example.com/about-us'

if(!strURL.EndsWith("/"))
    strURL = strURL + "/";
```

But I will suggest to use [TrimEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=netframework-4.8)

```
string strURL = "https://www.example.com/about-us";
strURL = strURL.TrimEnd('/') + "/";
Console.WriteLine(strURL);

strURL = "https://www.example.com/about-us/";
strURL = strURL.TrimEnd('/') + "/";
Console.WriteLine(strURL);
```

Check [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NWd5gq)